# My whole is a fruit, what am I?

Tags: riddle

- My whole is a fruit.
- Remove my last letter I become a vegetable.
- Remove my first letter, I become a body part.
- Swap my first and last letter, I become a verb like harvest.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It is

> Pear

To get

> Pea, Ear, Reap (by removing last letter, first letter and swapping letters respectively)